Put value in column, not formula
I want to take values from column J, multiply them by -1 and put them in column I.
I have this line:
Range("I2:I9").Value = "=J2*-1"

which puts the formula in column I and calculates the value, but I simply want the value.
Alternatively if the values in column J can be multiplied by -1 in place, that would work too.
What can I do?

Try the 'educational' With Range("I2:I9"): .Formula = "=J2*-1": .Value = .Value: End With or the more efficient (dynamic) With Range("I2:I9"): .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate(.EntireRow.Columns("J").Address & "*-1"): End With. To copy in place (toggle +/-), you could use With Range("J2:J9"): .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate(.Address & "*-1"): End With.

This code inverts signals in place:
Sub invertSignal()

    Dim rng As Range                                  ' Declares rng as Range
    Set rng = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("J2:J9")  ' sets rng to desired range
    
    ' Loops for each cell in range, multiplying values by -1
    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Value = cell.Value * -1
    Next
    
End Sub


Try this - just tested and it works for me:
Sub InvertNum()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range

Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
Set rngSource = ws.Range("J2:J9")
Set rngTarget = ws.Range("I2:I9")
rngTarget.Value = ws.Evaluate("-1 * " & rngSource.Address)

End Sub


To declare rngSource as a range, you must use Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range. The line arr = rngSource.Value is redundant. If rngSource has one area and more than one cell (it has both), rngSource.Value on the right side of an expression means that it's a 2D one-based array. In the line below, whatever was held in the dynamic array arr is overwritten no matter the size. Again, the right side of the expression is an array. So you could lose the arr variable and simplify with rngTarget.Value = Application.Evaluate("-1 * " & rngSource.Address.

Since you have IMO correctly referenced the worksheet (usually shortened with Set ws = ActiveSheet), you should use the safer Worksheet.Evaluate method i.e. ws.Evaluate("-1 * " & rngSource.Address) since when you pass the address (a string), how will Excel know on which sheet to look for it? With Application.Evaluate, it will be the ActiveSheet. Now consider this: you have decided that the sheet is Sheet1 in the workbook containing this code and you reference the sheet with Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"). If the sheet is not the active sheet, the code will fail.

Great tips - thank you! Edited to include. I forgot the As Range on rngSource - dumb error. I originally used arr to store the original values and do the calculations thinking it would be faster than operating on the range directly (especially in the case where the rngSource is much larger than 7 cells), but I'm actually not sure what happens under the covers using rngTarget.Value = ws.Evaluate(...) and if it is in fact slower.

Ignoring the redundant line, in your previous version, you take an array ws.Evaluate("-1 * " & rngSource.Address) that occupies some memory and copy it to another array arr that occupies some more memory before copying it to the destination range. In this version, you take the array and copy it to the range. The conclusion is obvious. Of course, you may not notice a difference even if thousands or more rows.

A simple "Evaluate" method may be [I2:I9] = [-J2:J9]

Another way to do it in place. You need a single empty cell, let it be M1:
Sub Inversion()
    With Range("M1")
        .Value = -1
        .Copy
        Range("J2:J9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply
        .ClearContents
    End With
End Sub

